# Create a changeset merging hierarchy in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm working with TFS with four branches: develop, test, preprod and prod. I've made three changesets: 10800, 10802 and 10803.

Is it possible to create a rule to say the changeset 10802 has to be merged in first, and then followed by 10802 and 10803?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

You seem to want to limit so that changesets are merged in the order of the changeset number. Merges can be done one or multiple changeset at a time given that it is possible to resolve any conflicts in the code. So it is really dependent on the actual changes whether you need to merge them together in chronological order or arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot set such a rule for the merging.

If you want to merge the changeset with the specific order, you can select the specific changeset manually to merge each time, or merge with the commands.

eg:
The following example merges all the changesets up to changeset 137 into branch2.

```
c:\projects>tf merge /version:C137 branch1 branch2 /recursive
```

See [Merge Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command) for details.